# Mongoose async await gets stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have just started learning mongoDB(mongoose) and nodejs(express). My web application used to work fine but now `await Photo.find()` takes for ever to resolve.

```
const Photo = require("../models/Photo");

const fetchAll = async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request was made');
  const page = req.query.page || 1;
  const uploads = await Photo.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .skip(page > 0 ? (page - 1) * 9 : 0)
    .limit(9);
  console.log('uploads were found');
  const hasMore = await Photo.find()
    .skip(page + 1 > 0 ? page * 9 : 0)
    .limit(9);
  console.log('hasMore was found');
  return res.json({ images: uploads, hasMore: hasMore.length >= 1 });
};

module.exports = fetchAll;
```

The console after making a request.

```
Request was made
```

As you can tell async function stucks on `await Photo.find()`.

I moved to previous commit and it has the same problem.

P.S every api on my web app turns to have this problem.

Comment: Did you connect to the DB?

Comment: Yes. But it takes about 30 secs to connect. Is that normal?

Comment: try calling `.exec()` after .limit

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Got the same result

Comment: Try running same query in MongoShell and check how much time it takes on shell

Comment: @ShotikoTopchishvili , great if you can move your functionality in try{//here}catch(e){} .. easy to log error in catch..

Comment: @bron1010 I have already tried that and no error is logged or thrown

Comment: 30 sec. for connecting sounds way too long. I’d rather investigate there, not in the code snippet you sent. Probably turn on Mongoose debug logging to see if this gives any clue: `mongoose.set('debug', true)`. Do the queries **ever** resolve and do subsequent queries **after** connecting run faster?

Comment: @qqilihq None of the queries resolve in my webapp

Comment: @ShotikoTopchishvili , Can you provide more details on what you exporting from '../models/Photo' .. just the mongoose schema or some wrapper ?

Comment: ```mongoose.connect(
  process.env.URI,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: true },
  () => console.log("Connected to DB!")
);``` Here's how I connect to the database.

Comment: `const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PhotoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  src: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Photos', PhotoSchema)` Here's the Photo model

Comment: Your code looks good, however need to inspect your db connection.
Try listening for events on connection and model events.
 `MyModel.events.on('error', err => console.log(err.message));
 mongoose.connection.on("open", () => {
    console.log("Emitted after connected")
 });` 
check for how long it takes or try connecting to local instance..

Comment: Is there an error handler in place? I don't see a try-catch block...

Comment: 30 seconds is the default server selection timeout. You have some kind of a connection problem.